# stream closed at java.base/java.io.fileinputstream.readbytes(native method)

Tags: java, spring-boot, inputstream, java-io

I am facing a stream closed exception: The behavior is triggered when I have more than one file to treat.

```
      try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(out);
            ...
            for (FileDto fileDto : listePdfFiles) {
                String fileBaseName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(fileDto.getName());
                String fileExtension = "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileDto.getName());
                if (duplicateFileName.containsKey(fileDto.getName())) {
                    if (duplicateFileName.get(fileDto.getName()) > 0) {
                        fileBaseName += "(" + duplicateFileName.get(fileDto.getName()) + ")";
                    }
                    duplicateFileName.put(fileDto.getName(),               duplicateFileName.get(fileDto.getName()) + 1);
                }
                ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileBaseName + fileExtension);
                zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = fileDto.getContent().read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                    zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
                }
            }
            zipOut.closeEntry();
            zipOut.close();
            String random = String.format("%s", RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8));
            try(InputStream archive = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray())) {
            return FileDto.builder().content(archive)
                    ...
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exporting report to PDF error: ", e);
        }
```

I debugged the process: the first file is handled successfully, but the second file is disregarded at '(length = fileDto.getContent().read(bytes)', and no processing is performed on the second file, resulting in a 400 error.

I tweaked the code slightly by adding a try-catch to handle the exception, and as a result, the zip file containing the two files can be downloaded, however the second file is broken.

Comment: Can you please modularise the code? this is highly unreadable, and is difficult to comprehend what is the requirement.

Comment: You get what you ask for. When you return from the `try(InputStream archive = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray())) { … }`, it will close the `InputStream`, as that’s what `try(…)` is for: ensuring that the resource is closed when you exit the block.